# Android 4.2 - how execute shell command on system boot?

Tags: boot, command-line, scripts

How do I do that? I have root access and the it's a custom build of AOSP project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a shell script file, one command per line,  place it under /system/etc/init.d and fix the permissions for init.d folder and shell script should be named 99NAME ..

Init.d is used for applying network tweaks on boot... You can use it to run other shell script files also.